# ProcessBuilder vs Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, runtime.exec, processbuilder

Which one is better? By better I mean which one has better security, etc. (not ease of use).

Comment: What do you mean with 'has better security'?

Answer (score 32):

Ease of use is the only real difference between those two.

Note that ease of use can lead to security by helping to avoid mis-use.

At least on OpenJDK 6 `Runtime.exec()` is implemented using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)
    throws IOException {
    return new ProcessBuilder(cmdarray)
        .environment(envp)
        .directory(dir)
        .start();
}
```

Comment: Except that `Runtime.exec` has overloads that take `command` as a single `String` and tokenize it, but in `ProcessBuilder` a single `String` is handled as a vararg `String[1]` -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec