# Passing a path to exec

Tags: java

I am trying to use the exec function. The path to the executable contains spaces and this is giving me grief
My code looks like this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ASL\\_ASL Software Suite_installation.exe\"", null, new File("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ASL\\_ASL Software Suite_installation\""));
```

When this is executed I get an exception -

```
Cannot run program ""c:\Program"
```

I would be grateful if someone can give me some help in solving this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use this instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: You are trying to use the `Runtime.exec()` function. Be specific.

Answer (score 4):

From [`Runtime.exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

> Executes the specified string command in a separate process with the specified environment and working directory.
>
> This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form `exec(command, envp, dir)` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation `exec(cmdarray, envp, dir)`, where `cmdarray` is an array of all the tokens in `command`.
>
> **More precisely, the `command` string is broken into tokens using a `StringTokenizer` created by the call `new StringTokenizer(command)` with no further modification of the character categories. The tokens produced by the tokenizer are then placed in the new string array `cmdarray`, in the same order.**

This means the first string is broken into tokens, regardless of the outer quotes. Use the [`Runtime.exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) version to avoid the tokenization of the executable path.

Or, use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
File d = new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/ASL/_ASL Software Suite_installation");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(d.getAbsolutePath() + "/main.exe");
Process p = pb.directory(d)
              .start();
```

See:

- [Why should avoid using Runtime.exec() in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723346/why-should-avoid-using-runtime-exec-in-java)
- [ProcessBuilder vs Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886829/processbuilder-vs-runtime-exec)

Comment: Thanks for the hint - how can I arrange things such that the program wont continue until the called program exits?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to quote the filenames again. Java will take care of it for you just give the proper filename as a string like so

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ASL\\_ASL Software Suite_installation.exe", 
    null, 
    new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ASL\\_ASL Software Suite_installation"));
```

Comment: This is not working either. I tried:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/Disk Utility",null, new File("/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/"));
` and it wouldnt work.